# Make my @Test GET request work in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, testing

beginner here. I have created an API in Spring Boot using java and I want to test whether the GET request returns a 200. I'm not interested in checking what's returned (a JSON object) I just want to check whether this connection works. I have tried this code so far:

```
@Test
    void getRequest() throws Exception {
        // this doesn't work because a ResultMatcher is needed
        this.mvc.perform(get("/currencies")).andExpect(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

        //tried this too and I get "Cannot resolve method 'assertThat(int, int)'"
        RequestBuilder request = get("/currencies");
        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(request).andReturn();
        assertThat(result.getResponse().getStatus(), 200);

    }
```

On the first statement, I'm literally saying "do a get request for this base url and expect a http accepted status" it isn't liking it. Am I asking for too much?

my second attempt I'm saying "Make a MvcResult object and store the result of the GET request within it. Then compare it to the status code of 200"

Here is the full class

```
import com.example.CoinAPI.controller.CoinController;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.RequestBuilder;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;

@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
class CoinApiApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private CoinController controller;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertThat(controller).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    void getRequest() throws Exception {
        // this doesn't work
        this.mvc.perform(get("/currencies")).andExpect(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

        //tried this too
        RequestBuilder request = get("/currencies");
        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(request).andReturn();
        assertThat(result.getResponse().getStatus(), 200);

    }


}
```

How do I make this work? I have searched endlessly around Google and youtube. nothing is helping me. I am missing something, I am sure

Comment: You're looking for `andExpect(status().isAccepted())`. I very strongly recommend looking at the official tutorials.

Comment: Hello, your suggestion was very close! The unit test failed because expected value returns 202 while the actual value is 200. I fixed it by using this ```status().is2xxSuccessful()``` and it worked! Thanks very much mate